# jquery $(this).attr('id') is giving undefined result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fetch details of the id which element is changed.
But when I am trying to find it using below code, it is giving error.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Enter city name" class="get_neighborhood" maxlength="30" id="city" value="P" name="city" data-invalid="">
<input type="text" placeholder="State code" maxlength="2" class="get_neighborhood" required="required" id="state" value="AA" name="state">
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".get_neighborhood").on('change',function() {
        city = $('#city').val();
        ajax_url = 'alternate_address/ajax_get_country/';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // or 'POST', whatever you want.
            dataType: 'json', // output_value will be a plain text string.
            data: {
                city: city
            },
            url: ajax_url,
            beforeSend: function(msg) {                

            },
            success: function(output_value) {
                myid = $(this).attr('id');                
                //var id=this.id;
                console.log(myid.toSource());

            },
            error: function(output_value) {
                alert('err');                    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this gives error that myid is undefined.
when I change city or state field.

Comment: this is refering to you success function

Comment: I do not understand why give -1 or this question. ???

Comment: Thank you all for quick replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cache the `$(this)` reference outside that ajax call and use it inside of that.

**Full code:**

```
$(".get_neighborhood").on('change',function() {

        city = $('#city').val();
        ajax_url = 'alternate_address/ajax_get_country/';
        _this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // or 'POST', whatever you want.
            dataType: 'json', // output_value will be a plain text string.
            data: {
                city: city
            },
            url: ajax_url,
            beforeSend: function(msg) {                

            },
            success: function(output_value) {
                myid = _this.attr('id');                
                //var id=this.id;
                console.log(myid.toSource());

            },
            error: function(output_value) {
                alert('err');                    
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: all answers are same.... but you wrote it first. thanks, :)

Answer (score 1):

In ajax, you lose the element event context so you cannot access it inside ajax, what you need to do is store it's id after event in variable and the use it in scucess:

```
$(".get_neighborhood").on('change',function() {
        city = $('#city').val();
     var Id = this.id;

     //or

    var element = $(this);

......

.....

success: function(output_value) {
                myid = Id;            

}
```

or store element reference and use like this :

```
$(".get_neighborhood").on('change',function() {

        var element = $(this);

    ......

    .....

    success: function(output_value) {
                    myid = $(element).attr("id");            

    }
```

Comment: thank you .... ehsan aapka :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using $(this) in the wrong context. Store event source in some variable and use it in success.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".get_neighborhood").on('change',function() {
        source = $(this); //Store $(this);
        city = $('#city').val();
        ajax_url = 'alternate_address/ajax_get_country/';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // or 'POST', whatever you want.
            dataType: 'json', // output_value will be a plain text string.
            data: {
                city: city
            },
            url: ajax_url,
            beforeSend: function(msg) {                

            },
            success: function(output_value) {
                myid = source.attr('id'); //Use source here.                
                //var id=this.id; 
                console.log(myid.toSource());

            },
            error: function(output_value) {
                alert('err');                    
            }
        });
    });
});
```